# WPF Command binding with method returning bool

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have two methods that do almost the two things:

```
    public static void ShowThing()
    {
        // code..
    }
```

and

```
    public static bool TryShowThing()
    {
        if(condition)
        {
            // same code above..
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

At the moment I'm binding a button's *Command* to the `void` method and it does what it should.
Problem is that now I'm cleaning up the code and to avoid coupling I wanted to bind the button to the `bool` method and that won't work.

Is `Command={Binding BooleandReturningMedhod}` even allowed in xaml?

Apparently nobody on the internet has ever had this problem before so I think I'm missing something here...

Comment: You cannot directly bind to a method.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind directly to a method.

What i think what you really wanna achieve is something like this

Code:

```
ShowThingCommand { get; } = new RelayCommand((o) => ShowThing(),(o) => condition)
```

RelayCommand:

```
public class RelayCommand : ICommand    
{    
    private Action<object> execute;    
    private Func<object, bool> canExecute;    

    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged    
    {    
        add { CommandManager.RequerySuggested += value; }    
        remove { CommandManager.RequerySuggested -= value; }    
    }    

    public RelayCommand(Action<object> execute, Func<object, bool> canExecute = null)    
    {    
        this.execute = execute;    
        this.canExecute = canExecute;    
    }    

    public bool CanExecute(object parameter)    
    {    
        return this.canExecute == null || this.canExecute(parameter);    
    }    

    public void Execute(object parameter)    
    {    
        this.execute(parameter);    
    }    
}
```

XAML:

```
<Button Command={Binding ShowThingCommand } />
```

Important part is the `CanExecute` method, when it returns `false` your `Button` gets disabled